# What "near" means for you?

Tags: measuring, geolocation, range

guys!
We have web-portal and there is a filter "near subway station ...".
So I am curious about what "near subway station" means specifically for you?
50m, 100m, 1km, 2km, 10km and so on?
Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: For me near means short walking distance, so within 500 meters. I live in a public transport dense area though so I can imagine this being different for you.

Comment: You're effectively conducting an user test asking for opinions here. Try using something like https://usabilityhub.com/ for tests like this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will depend on the general availability of subway stations for your users. In general how many subway stations exist within a 50km radius? If several, then 50km could serve as "near" for the users.

"Near" should serve the purpose of showing the "n" closest stations. You certainly don't want 0 to be the result, and ideally would not want more than 5-10. A study of the distance between subway stations would yield this answer.